# How to checkout a branch from azure devops pipeline?

Tags: github, azure-devops

I kept trigger to cloud_singlesignon branch.

But my pipeline saved to azure-pipelines and the default branch to the repo is master.

But the checkout not happening from cloud_singlesignon.

I observed, it is checking out from branch where the pipeline is saved(azure-pipelines), not the one in trigger

Any idea how to troubleshoot this?

my pipeline:

```
trigger:
- cloud_singlesignon
 
resources:
  - repo: self
 
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
 
steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
 
- script: |
    wget https://github.com/adoptium/temurin16-binaries/releases/download/jdk-16.0.2%2B7/OpenJDK16U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_16.0.2_7.tar.gz
    pwd
    ls -lRt
  displayName: 'Download jdk'
- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'LocalDirectory'
    jdkFile: 'OpenJDK16U-jdk_x64_linux_hotspot_16.0.2_7.tar.gz'
    jdkDestinationDirectory: '/opt/jdkcustom'
    cleanDestinationDirectory: true
- script: |
    java -version
    ls -lRt
    pwd
    ls $(Pipeline.Workspace)
    git log --oneline | wc -l
```